# Conditional Expectation as Almost Sure Convergence

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, conditional-expectation

I'm currently studying the properties of conditional expectation, and I came across this definition in A Probability Path (Resnick) that seems a bit confusing.

The statement is: If $X \in G; X \in L_1$ then $E[X|G]=X$ almost surely.

Proof: We prove this by merely noting that $X$ is $G-$measurable and $\int_{A}XdP=\int_{A}XdP$ $\forall A \in G$

My confusion:

Previously, when I studied almost sure convergence, the definition was presented as a **sequence** of random variables converging a.s to a limiting random variable with probability one. However, here I don't understand what the intuition is behind two random variables being equal a.s? I do not see a sequence ($X_n$) anywhere?

Also, I understand that conditional expectation is a Random-Nikodym derivative; therefore, by definition $\int_{A}E[X|G]dP=\int_{A}XdP$. However, I am confused about how this proof is enough to conclude a.s convergence.

Thanks!

Comment: It means that $\mathsf{P}(X=\mathsf{E}[X\mid G])=1$. Moreover, it has nothing to do with the a.s. convergence of a sequence of r.v.s.

Comment: Ok.. so in a way there are two definitions for a.s convergence? One for a sequence and one for a RV?

Comment: a.s. _signifies_ ''almost surely'', it actually means ''almost everywhere with respect to the probability measure under consideration.'' (Almost everywhere means that the _complement_ of the statement is a null set.)

Comment: So intuitively what it's saying is that the rv X will almost surely take on the same values as $E[X|G]$?